# Redirect non-www and www http requests to https://www

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I need to redirect all non-www request and http request on my website to https://www.example.com.
I use an Apache server but I can't find anything useful to help me do that. 
Currently I use the .htaccess file to redirect non-www request to www.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
I am using CloudFlare CDN so I needed to add this code to redirect non https requests.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L, R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: This could be something in your application or server config causing the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this single rule to add both redirects:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: You should have mentioned `CloudFlare` in question.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it through PHP also, please check below code to do this :-

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == ""){
    $redirect = "https://".str_replace("www.","",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: $redirect"); } 

$protocol = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://"; if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) !== 'www.') {
    header('Location: '.$protocol.'www.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    exit; }
```